# Problem finding proper angle (in degrees) for trendline created in matplotlib using polyfit

Tags: matplotlib, degrees, trendline

If someone could please explain/show how to get the proper angle read...
In my example, the Angle should be between 40-45 degrees but I only show 5.71 degrees or just over 90 degrees (if I try reverse x/y).  I have searched for awhile which has got me this far but I don't see how to fix this.. Help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1.1,1.4,1.3,1.6,1.1,1.6,1.7,2.2,1.9]

plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', markersize=1, color="green")
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)  
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

degree = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y[-1] - y[0], x[-1] - x[0]))
degree2 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(x[-1] - x[0], y[-1] - y[0]))
print(degree, degree2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is trying to figure this out. Method can find angle,radian,slope, and intersect without plotting.
plt.axis('equal') is needed to plot the angle correctly...
Would like a better way if anyone knows to get the angle to display properly without zooming in.

Thank you to everyone for your knowledge and help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
from statistics import mean
import math

def best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys):
    m = (((mean(xs)*mean(ys)) - mean(xs*ys)) / ((mean(xs)*mean(xs)) - mean(xs*xs)))    
    b = mean(ys) - m*mean(xs)    
    return m, b

ys = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
#ys = np.asarray([1.03,1.035,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.08,1.12,1.09,1.15])
xs = np.arange(len(ys))
m, b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys)
angle_in_radians = math.atan(m)
angle_in_degrees = math.degrees(angle_in_radians)
print("Slope=" + str(m))
print("Intercept=" + str(b))
print("Radians=" + str(angle_in_radians))
print("Degrees=" + str(angle_in_degrees))    
regression_line = []
for x in xs:
    regression_line.append((m*x)+b)
plt.scatter(xs,ys,color='#003F72')
plt.plot(xs, regression_line)    
plt.axis('equal')    
plt.show()
```